# How do I wrap text around an arbitrary relative position image?

Tags: html, css

Below I have an example of were I'm at. I have an image that will appear with an arbitrary location and size determined by the user. I want the text of that section to wrap around the image just like it does in Word (when you set multi-line text wrap for image).

Float left and right work when the image is all the way to the left or right, but if I offset the location of the image, the text wraps where the image was before the offset. (and there is no float center) And margin/padding just effectively change the image size, not let text wrap on the other side as well.

I am interested in achieving the same effect as what Word allows. The CSS, HTML, and if absolutely necessary, the library(s) used are all fine to change.

```css
.mockImage {
  background-color: blue;
  position: relative;
  top: 5em;
  left: 10em;
  height: 120px;
  width: 60px;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="mockImage"></div>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam dapibus faucibus lacus ac consequat. Aenean a neque ut lacus vulputate tempor id id erat. Praesent consequat nibh dolor, id mattis massa accumsan nec. Nam eu tristique eros. Quisque hendrerit
suscipit mi. Sed viverra purus non sapien placerat varius. Praesent blandit condimentum dolor, quis finibus libero molestie eget. Quisque vulputate velit eu feugiat facilisis. Donec risus sapien, sollicitudin hendrerit urna id, mollis eleifend nibh. Phasellus
dolor dui, semper quis tortor varius, posuere posuere velit. Cras auctor dui et magna fringilla, eu rhoncus tortor facilisis. Vestibulum leo sem, vulputate eget luctus eu, aliquet vel ipsum. Aliquam ac dui et justo cursus tincidunt. Etiam fringilla bibendum
nibh, nec auctor ex pellentesque id. Nam commodo placerat lectus, sit amet condimentum ante pellentesque a. Etiam ac maximus libero, id faucibus purus. Praesent odio sapien, consequat in mi id, tincidunt aliquam augue. Duis id ligula sodales, ullamcorper
enim a, ullamcorper nisl. Phasellus tempus ultrices lacus sit amet congue. Integer a rutrum lacus. Sed in accumsan quam. Proin mollis tortor vitae lacus gravida eleifend. Cras in risus ornare, finibus ante et, interdum diam. Fusce nec odio sodales dolor
venenatis sagittis. Duis lacinia rhoncus eros, eu sodales magna pulvinar vitae. Curabitur cursus dui in sapien accumsan luctus. Aenean placerat nulla felis, a egestas odio pulvinar in. Duis lacinia turpis felis, eu pretium eros ullamcorper ac. Aliquam
vitae sagittis neque, non posuere est. Phasellus varius, tortor at luctus imperdiet, dui risus rutrum risus, vitae pulvinar neque odio eget turpis. Fusce eget gravida elit. Suspendisse quis orci blandit, interdum nunc ut, pulvinar dui. Aenean commodo
metus mi, vel tincidunt elit convallis vitae. Quisque et metus sollicitudin, euismod purus at, porta augue. Ut pretium sem ligula, sed fermentum nibh auctor ac. Sed eu leo eu quam pharetra aliquam id et ipsum. Aliquam scelerisque leo quis mauris aliquam,
eu suscipit felis sollicitudin. Etiam laoreet velit tempor scelerisque mollis. Sed ultrices pharetra mauris, eu dictum erat fringilla nec. Ut lectus urna, imperdiet id posuere ac, consequat et nisi. Donec et egestas metus, vitae rhoncus augue. Pellentesque
sed risus in mauris faucibus euismod ornare a arcu. Mauris eu finibus libero, sit amet volutpat massa. Fusce egestas, ipsum quis vulputate ullamcorper, diam ante fermentum ante, at lobortis urna lacus et leo. Ut eget molestie diam. Mauris cursus urna
eget dapibus tempor. Proin orci nunc, imperdiet ut enim eu, viverra sodales mi. Proin sit amet lorem ultrices, facilisis erat sed, fermentum augue. Aenean ut arcu eget enim posuere efficitur non ut ex. Sed vel lorem eleifend, vulputate massa sed, efficitur
diam. Sed pretium ultricies interdum. In auctor volutpat arcu eu porta. Proin odio lorem, scelerisque a erat a, facilisis ornare metus. Maecenas bibendum aliquam lectus, quis porttitor nisl maximus non. In eget orci suscipit, blandit odio eget, ultricies
ligula. Donec eu lacinia magna. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia curae; Etiam maximus tempus arcu, eget fermentum ligula vestibulum at. Mauris eu neque leo. Aliquam erat volutpat.
```

Comment: Suggest you look at css shapes and the property shape-outside.

Comment: That CSS does help with complex shape support, but it doesn't help with wrapping text on both sides of the image.

Comment: Unfortunately there is no CSS method of achieving what you want as far as I know but you might be able to fake it with multiple divs and separated paragraphs.

Comment: `shape-outside` only allows you to make the shape that you want to float stuff around, not necessarily be a rectangle. It doesn't change the fact, that you will still have to float the element you are applying this to, left or right, to get _any_ "flow around" effect in the first place. Having text flow around an element on both sides at the same time, is not a thing that currently exists.